# Running through an environmental error during deploying django app on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, django-rest-framework

I have created virtual env with anaconda prompt and created my django project in that env. I have created repository on github and push my code there and also create app on heroku but when i am running this `git push heroku main`  command, it showing me an error which I have given below:

**ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build/80754af9/asgiref_1605055780383/work'**..

traceback:

```
PS C:\Users\AHMED\newrest\source> git push heroku main
Enumerating objects: 48, done.
Counting objects: 100% (48/48), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (44/44), done.
Writing objects: 100% (48/48), 16.22 KiB | 615.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 48 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.8.6
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.8.5
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Processing /tmp/build/80754af9/asgiref_1605055780383/work
remote:        ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build/80754af9/asgiref_1605055780383/work'
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to restlearnsignup.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/restlearnsignup.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/restlearnsignup.git'
```

requirement file

```
asgiref @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/asgiref_1605055780383/work
astroid==2.4.1
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.4
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
colorama==0.4.3
cryptography==3.3.1
decorator==4.4.2
Django==3.0.3
django-rest-knox==4.1.0
djangorestframework==3.12.2
dodgy==0.2.1
dynaconf==3.1.2
flake8==3.8.3
flake8-polyfill==1.0.2
gender-guesser==0.4.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
hvac==0.10.5
idna==2.10
isort==4.3.21
knox==0.1.11
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
loguru==0.5.3
mccabe==0.6.1
pep8-naming==0.10.0
prospector==1.3.0
pycodestyle==2.6.0
pycparser==2.20
pydocstyle==5.0.2
pyflakes==2.2.0
pylint==2.5.2
pylint-celery==0.3
pylint-django==2.0.15
pylint-flask==0.6
pylint-plugin-utils==0.6
pytz @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pytz_1606604771399/work
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.25.0
requirements-detector==0.7
setoptconf==0.2.0
shortuuid==1.0.1
six==1.15.0
snowballstemmer==2.0.0
sqlparse @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sqlparse_1602184451250/work
toml==0.10.1
tqdm @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/tqdm_1607369919789/work
urllib3==1.26.2
validators==0.18.1
whitenoise==5.2.0
win32-setctime==1.0.3
wincertstore==0.2
wrapt==1.12.1
```

Anyone who know how to resolve this error ?. I learning deployment and I don't know much about this. I research but couldn't found anything helpful.

Comment: show us your requirements file

Comment: @iklinac I updated the question with that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your requirements to point to asgiref version instead of temporary file

For example

```
asgiref==3.3.1
```

Comment: I updated my requirement file with `asgiref==3.3.1` and it resolved the error but after proceeding further it gave me some kind of similar error as you can see **ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build/80754af9/pytz_1606604771399/work'**

Comment: you have to do similar for the rest of packages that do not have numbers

Comment: Can i give **3.3.1** to rest of all ?

Comment: no you have to use proper version for each of packages

Comment: Okay so it means i can just put latest versions of rest of entries.

Comment: I excuse. I searched about pytz latest version but this is different than rest of all. Everything is now working expect the pytz. Can you please fix that out too.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$ pip list
```

And edit the *requirements.txt* file to replace the temporary file with the actual version of the packages